# console.log causes error when used in Electron main process

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, concurrently

I am writing an Electron app and whenever I used `console.log()` or any of its variants in the main process, the app will crash and it will open a popup with the following message:

```
Error X

A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
  Error: open EISDIR
  at new Socket (node:net:413:13)
  at createWritableStdioStream (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:78:18)
  at process.getStderr [as stderr] (node:internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread:170:12)
  at console.get (node:internal/console/constructor:220:44)
  at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:347:50)
  at console.warn (node:internal/console/constructor:382:61)
  at loadApplicationPackage (D:\Code\Node\CraftPanel\app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asa...:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Code\Node\CraftPanel\app\node_modules\electron\dist\resources\default_app.asar\...:9)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
  at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1296:10)
```

Has anyone else encountered this? I haven't used Electron in a while but in previous projects I had no issue logging messages using `console.log()` before.

I'm writing the app in Typescript, running it on Windows through WSL2, and I'm running it through `concurrently` so I can launch my React frontend and Electron app in parallel.